# Find all functions $f$ analytic in a region that satisfy the following.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Find all functions $f$ analytic in a region $|z| < R$, that satisfy $f(0) = i$ and $|f(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z$ in the region.

I was (only) able to make this observation.

$f(0) = i \rightarrow |f(0)| = 1$, but since $|f(z)| \leq 1$, thus I claim the maximum modulus is achieved in the interior of the region.

But now I do not know how to proceed on.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Comment: The only analytic function who achieve their maximum in the interior of a connected open region are constant, by the maximum modulus.

Comment: Damn, that slipped my mind.... Thank you